# Can't get jQuery .off() to remove event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I can't seem to figure out why my .off('click') jQuery method isn't working considering I am removing the event binding from '.reveal-menu'.  The first animation works fine as each div moves to its respective location in increments of 78.  But I can't seem to get it to go back.

JQUERY

```
$(function(){

  var userMenuDivs = $('#user-menu div:gt(1)');
  userMenuDivs.hide();


  $('.reveal-menu').on('click',
    function(){
      $(this).addClass('down');
      iconSpacerCount = 78;
      userMenuDivs.show();
      $.each(userMenuDivs, function(index,value){
        $(this).animate({top:iconSpacerCount},200);
        iconSpacerCount += 78;});  
  });

  $('.reveal-menu').off('click',
    function(){
      $(this).removeClass('down');
      iconSpacerCount = 0;
      $.each(userMenuDivs, function(index,value){
        $(this).animate({top:iconSpacerCount});
      });
    });



});
```

HTML

```
  <div id="user-menu">
    <div class="reveal-menu">
    <i class="fa fa-plus fa-lg"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="post-option">
      <a href="#" class="fa fa-pencil fa-2x"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="search-option">
      <a href="#" class="fa fa-search fa-lg"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="chat-option">
      <a href="#" class="fa fa-comments fa-lg"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="profile-option">
      <a href="#" class="fa fa-user fa-lg"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="friends-option">
      <a href="#" class="fa fa-users fa-lg"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="organizations-option">
      <a href="#" class="fa fa-building-o fa-lg"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="public-figures-option">
      <a href="#" class="fa fa-bullhorn fa-lg"></a>
    </div>

    <div class="sign-out-option">
      <a href="#" class="fa fa-sign-out fa-lg"></a>
    </div>


  </div>
```

Here is a link to a video to show you what I'm doing. 
https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/3270373/2016-06-01_21-57-20.mp4

Comment: What's your actual goal, just to have the click work one time?

Comment: Click on for menu and icons to appear and animate.  Click off for them to animate back and disappear.

Comment: When passing a function to `.off` it is used to remove that specific handler, it isn't used to add another handler after taking off the others

Answer (score 0):

The `.off` is used to remove the events. It is not used to add the opposite event of `.on`. You can switch the `click` event between two function like this:

```js
$(function() {
  var userMenuDivs = $('#user-menu div:gt(1)');
  userMenuDivs.hide();

  $('.reveal-menu').on('click', revealMenuOn);
});

function revealMenuOn() {
  $(this).addClass('down');
  $('#user-menu div:gt(1)').slideDown( "slow" );
  $('.reveal-menu').off('click').on('click', revealMenuOff);
}

function revealMenuOff() {
  $(this).removeClass('down');
  $('#user-menu div:gt(1)').slideUp( "slow" );
  $('.reveal-menu').off('click').on('click', revealMenuOn);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="user-menu">
  <div class="reveal-menu">
    <i class="fa fa-plus fa-lg">1</i>
  </div>

  <div class="post-option">
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-pencil fa-2x">2</a>
  </div>
  <div class="search-option">
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-search fa-lg">3</a>
  </div>
  <div class="chat-option">
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-comments fa-lg">4</a>
  </div>
  <div class="profile-option">
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-user fa-lg">5</a>
  </div>
  <div class="friends-option">
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-users fa-lg">6</a>
  </div>
  <div class="organizations-option">
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-building-o fa-lg">7</a>
  </div>
  <div class="public-figures-option">
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-bullhorn fa-lg">8</a>
  </div>
  <div class="sign-out-option">
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-sign-out fa-lg">9</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can try .unbind() event.

```js
 $('.reveal-menu').unbind('click',
    function(){
      $(this).removeClass('down');
      iconSpacerCount = 0;
      $.each(userMenuDivs, function(index,value){
        $(this).animate({top:iconSpacerCount});
      });
    });
```

Comment: "As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() and .off() methods are preferred to attach and remove event handlers on elements."

Comment: Passing a *new*, anonymous function to `.off()` *or* `.unbind()` won't help at all.